# How to export large amount of data fast via Web API

Tags: c#, csv, export, entity-framework-6

I'm using ASP.NET Web API 2 (.NET 4.6.1) and AngularJS on the client side. My requirement is to export the tables data in either CSV or Excel format. I cannot use bcp or sqlcmd because of security reasons. Also, cannot use DTS package as the parameters will be coming from web UI and I need to pass it to stored procedure to retrieve the result and send back the file via api.

Currently, I'm trying to read all 500K records using Entity Framework 6 to `IEnumerable<T>` type. My table has around 500K records with 40+ columns. I was trying to convert it to CSV and then return as plain text and open in browser as blob.

Questions:

1. Is there any better way to export and return the data within few seconds.
2. If `IEnumerable` to CSV is the only way then should i first write it file and return file or return plain text as response from web api.
3. I have tried few code from the web to convert `IEnumerable` to CSV (using `String.Join` and `StringBuilder` and are not efficient).

Appreciate, if anyone can share how large amounts of data can be converted to CSV very fast or other way to export data.

Comment: Nothing will be *"very fast"* with 500K rows of data

Answer (score 0):

I dont' think it will work that fast, as we are looking at (roughly) 200MB dataset that you first pull from DB and then send it to client. You could try using DotNetZip library to zip the CSV before sneding to client...

Comment: Is there anyway I can invoke bcp on db server from web server and let bcp export the data.? I'm restricted to use xp_cmdshell in sql server?

Comment: Not that I know of. In the past I have used several techniques to get the data from DB faster... One of them is to run several queries in parallel. For example, if you need data to be returned for the last 8 days, then you could run 8 queries for each day. This trick may or may not work, depending on network configuration.

Comment: My issue is not with data retrieval from database. My stored procedure hardly takes 60 seconds to return the data. My problem is convert to csv or excel and send it back to client.

Comment: Could you, perhaps, describe the problem a bit more? Do you not know how to do it, or does it take too much time to generate CSV file, or does it take too much time to transfer it to the client?

Comment: Too much time to convert to comma delimited value.

Comment: One way to increase the speed of StringBuilder is to create it with initial size of the entire file it will hold (`var sb = new StringBuilder(200 000 000);`). Another way would be to skip the StringBuilder and write directly to file and then send the file to the client.